# Change the default application (for a file extension) via script/command line?

Tags: applescript, command-line, defaults

Is there a way to define the default application for a file extension via an Apple script, command line command (like `defaults write [...]`).

I know that you can change it manually via the information panel or by using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) but as I have to setup many machines and user accounts I would like to find a way to automate the process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) is a shell utility that enables using a text file to configure the default applications for file types and URL schemes.

For example save a file like this as `~/.duti`:

```
com.gnu.Emacs public.plain-text all 
com.gnu.Emacs public.unix-executable all
org.videolan.vlc .mkv all
```

Then run `duti ~/.duti`.

You can install duti with `brew install duti` or by running `wget https://github.com/fitterhappier/duti/archive/duti-1.5.2.tar.gz;tar -xf duti-1.5.2.tar.gz;cd duti-duti-1.5.2;./configure;make;sudo make install`.

Comment: This seems promising, although I cannot seem to compile it on OS X 10.7.x or 10.8.x: `checking which SDK to use... configure: error: darwin12.0.0 is not a supported system`.

Comment: The binary in the pkg installer still works for me on 10.8.

Comment: I see. For future reference, here’s the link to that download: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/duti/duti/duti-1.5.0/duti-1.5.0.pkg.tar.gz

Comment: Does this work on 10.8? I set the default application to open `.avi` files to Quicktime Player (using Finder → _Get Info_ → _Open with… → _Change all_), then ran `duti -s org.videolan.vlc public.avi all` to use VLC instead, then [restarted LaunchServices](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49536/4408) — but it seemed to have no effect. (See [list of system-declared UTIs](http://mths.be/utis).)

Comment: It works for me at least. It shouldn't require rebuilding the Launch Services database or restarting or anything. If you take a look at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`, duti converts most filename extensions to UTIs automatically, so you can usually specify the types like `.avi` instead of `public.avi`. The UTIs of some filename extensions depend on the applications that are installed.

Comment: @LauriRanta I just installed duti on OS X 10.9 through homebrew, but when I created the .duti file and ran `duti ~/.duti`, I got `role "all " unrecognized`. Just FYI, I had to comment out the first two lines of your sample code and it worked for VLC.

Comment: @macmadness There has to be a linefeed at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 18):

Launch Services is responsible for default file associations.

Let's say I wanted to change all text files to open in Sublime Text 2.

First I need the kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier for Sublime Text 2. I can use [mdls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/mdls.1.html) to get this information:

```
> mdls /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app 
_kTimeMachineIsCreationMarker  = 1
_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot    = 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot    = 2012-02-22 03:49:19 +0000
kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier      = "com.sublimetext.2"
....snip....
```

I can find out the content type value for text files by inspecting one of them with [mdls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/mdls.1.html):

```
> mdls test.txt 
kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2012-03-25 04:18:50 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2012-03-25 04:18:50 +0000
kMDItemContentType             = "public.plain-text"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded               = 2012-03-25 04:18:50 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName             = "test.txt"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = 2012-03-25 04:18:50 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = 2012-03-25 04:18:50 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = 0
kMDItemFSLabel                 = 0
kMDItemFSName                  = "test.txt"
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = 975
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = 501
kMDItemFSSize                  = 975
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemKind                    = "Plain Text"
kMDItemLogicalSize             = 975
kMDItemPhysicalSize            = 4096
```

In this case I'll change the default application for all `public.plain-text` types.

To do this I type:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{ LSHandlerContentType = \"public.plain-text\"; LSHandlerRoleAll = \"com.sublimetext.2\"; }'
```

If I want the changes to take effect I'll need to restart Launch Services like so:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

And to give credit where credit is due, I learned about this approach from this stackoverflow.com question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172226/how-to-set-default-application-for-specific-file-types-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

[This post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal) also contains some helpful information. To learn more about LaunchServices, [here's a link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/LaunchServicesReference.pdf) to Apple's developer documentation on it. Go to the section entitled *LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType* (page 48).